# I convert the sql stored procedure into oracle but getting error on line

Tags: oracle

Following is my stored procedure. It gives me error:

> (PLS-00103 (65: 199): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:. ) @ %).

Error occurs on this line:

```
v_SQLrecords := 'select distinct FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId as id,' || p_cols || ' ' || v_SQL || ' order by ' || p_cols || ' ' || p_order || ' OFFSET ' || CAST(p_rowsPerPage AS nvarchar2(500)) || ' * (' || CAST(p_pageNo AS nvarchar2(500)) || ' - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT ' || CAST(p_rowsPerPage AS nvarchar2(500)) || ' ROWS ONLY'
```

Please suggest me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetFeedbackQuestions (
p_LanguageName NCLOB DEFAULT NULL,
p_Crd timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
p_CrdBy number DEFAULT NULL,
p_IsDisabled number DEFAULT NULL, 
p_LanguageId number DEFAULT NULL,
p_Lmd timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
p_LmdBy number DEFAULT NULL,
p_Question  nvarchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_SequenceNo number DEFAULT NULL, 
p_RowCount number DEFAULT NULL, 
p_rowsPerPage number DEFAULT 10,
p_pageNo number DEFAULT 1,
p_cols NCLOB DEFAULT 'FeedbackQuestionId',
p_order NCLOB DEFAULT 'desc',cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS
  v_SQL NCLOB := ' from FEEDBACKQUESTIONS left join LANGUAGES on FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.LanguageId = LANGUAGES.LanguageId   where 1=1 ';
          v_ParamDefinition NCLOB;v_SQLrecords NCLOB;
BEGIN

  IF (p_LanguageName IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and LANGUAGES.LanguageName like  ''%' || p_LanguageName || '%''';
  END IF;
  IF (p_Crd IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and cast(FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.Crd as date)  = p_Crd';
  END IF;
  IF (p_CrdBy IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.CrdBy = p_CrdBy';
  END IF;
  IF (p_IsDisabled IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.IsDisabled = p_IsDisabled';
  END IF;
  IF (p_LanguageId IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.LanguageId = p_LanguageId';
  END IF;
  IF (p_Lmd IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and cast(FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.Lmd as date)  = p_Lmd';
  END IF;
  IF (p_LmdBy IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.LmdBy = p_LmdBy';
  END IF;
  IF (p_Question IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.Question like  ''%' || p_Question || '%''';
  END IF;
  IF (p_SequenceNo IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.SequenceNo = p_SequenceNo';
  END IF;
  v_ParamDefinition := 'p_LanguageName NCLOB,p_Crd TIMESTAMP(3) , p_CrdBy NUMBER(19) , p_IsDisabled NUMBER(1) , p_LanguageId NUMBER(19) , p_Lmd TIMESTAMP(3) , p_LmdBy NUMBER(19) , p_Question NCLOB , p_SequenceNo NUMBER(19) ';
  IF (p_cols IS NOT NULL)
  THEN
    p_cols := 'FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.' || p_cols || '';
  END IF;
  **v_SQLrecords := 'select distinct FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId as id,' || p_cols || ' ' || v_SQL || ' order by ' || p_cols || ' ' || p_order || ' OFFSET ' || CAST(p_rowsPerPage AS nvarchar2(500)) || ' * (' || CAST(p_pageNo AS nvarchar2(500)) || ' - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT ' || CAST(p_rowsPerPage AS nvarchar2(500)) || ' ROWS ONLY';**
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   v_SQLrecords using
                      v_ParamDefinition,
                        p_LanguageName,
                        p_Crd,
                        p_CrdBy,
                        p_IsDisabled,
                        p_LanguageId,
                        p_Lmd,
                        p_LmdBy,
                        p_Question,
                        p_SequenceNo;
  v_ParamDefinition := v_ParamDefinition || ', @RowCountOUT NCLOB OUTPUT';
  v_SQLrecords := 'select @RowCountOUT =count(distinct FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId) ' || v_SQL;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   v_SQLrecords using
                        v_ParamDefinition,
                        p_LanguageName,
                        p_Crd,
                        p_CrdBy,
                        p_IsDisabled,
                        p_LanguageId,
                        p_Lmd,
                        p_LmdBy,
                        p_Question,
                        p_SequenceNo,
                        RowCountOUT := p_RowCount OUT
  OPEN cur FOR SELECT
    p_RowCount FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: Keeping aside the syntax error in the part `RowCountOUT := p_RowCount OUT` (what should this do?) and the missing semicolon before the` OPEN cur`, what do you need to do with this procedure? Are you sure you need dynamic sql? I see more than one issue here, and I believe this can be strongly simplified. Try to build your procedure step by step instead of compiling it in a single run

Comment: this syntax `select @RowCountOUT =count(...` is not applicable to Oracle, and to be able to use `FETCH`, you version should be 12+, is that OK?

Comment: I am trying to convert sql stored procedure to oracle , I am solving line by line code but on above line which I asked in question not able to solve..I know this is another error but first I want to solve first one then second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply quote even to the `CAST` statements.

`CAST(p_rowsPerPage AS nvarchar2(500))` should be `'CAST(' || p_rowsPerPage || 'AS nvarchar2(500))'`

So your error line should be

```
v_SQLrecords := 'select distinct FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId as id,' 
             || p_cols || ' ' || v_SQL || ' order by ' || p_cols || ' ' || p_order 
             || ' OFFSET ' || 'CAST(' || p_rowsPerPage || 'AS nvarchar2(500))'  || ' * (' || 'CAST(' || p_pageNo || 'AS nvarchar2(500))'
             || ' - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT ' 
             || 'CAST(' || p_rowsPerPage || 'AS nvarchar2(500))'  || ' ROWS ONLY';
```

As mentioned in the chat, there are other errors as well. This is just for first line as you asked.